# How to prove that preference relation is continuous if the utility function represent the preference relation is continuous

Tags: microeconomics

The reverse of Debreu Theorem, have no idea how to start the question.

[image: original question]

Comment: Can you please define the problem, with some notation.

Comment: hi, I just add the original question. thx

Comment: Hi! Can you please include the definitions of these concepts (cont. preferences, cont. U func.) in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get you started:

We are *told* that this utility function represents a week preference relation.

Then (**transitivity**)

For $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in X$ suppose we get
$$u(x_1)\geq u(x_2)\geq u(x_3).$$
These are real numbers, and the chain weak inequality implies also
$$u(x_1) \geq u(x_3)$$

Since we have been told that this $u$ represents a preference relation, then it must be the case that
$$x_1 \succsim x_2,\;\; x_2 \succsim x_3,\;\; x_1 \succsim x_3. $$
This proves that this preference relation that is represented by this utility function is transitive.

**Completeness**
When you look at *any* two real numbers, is there a case where you are unable to say whether the one is higher than, lower than, or equal to, the other?

**Continuity**
You should follow the advice given in a comment to your post, which essentially tells you to put side by side the definitions of continuity of a real-valued function and that of preferences.